# How to deploy Powerbuilder application with ODBC connection?

Tags: connection, odbc, powerbuilder

my application works fine on the computer where I made it but on another
machines it displays error: "Transaction not connected".
I installed pack created by Runtime Packager and added a couple
of DLLs to the application path on the target machine. Still the same
problem.

My question is if I should use dnsless connection to make it work?
Or maybe inform the target PC about the required ODBC configuration?
If yes - how to do that?

I read a lot about odbc.ini, system variables, registry entries etc.
but now I got it all mixed up and have no clue what to do.

I'll be very grateful for your help.

Kris.

Comment: Have you instantiated a transaction object (SQLCA), set your connection parameters, then connected with it?

Comment: Which type of database are you connecting to? If it's Microsoft SQL Server, it used to be that you need to install the SQL Server Native Runtime. More info here: http://slapouttech.blogspot.com/2012/04/powerbuilder-and-sql-server-tips-on.html

Comment: @MattBalent: Yes, I did it all, it's working well on my PC.

I'm retriving data from Oracle database (two different servers).

Currently I'm trying to add proper registry entries on the client machine
to inform it about ODBC sources. The problem is that I can't find proper
entry on my PC to export it and import on the client. I would expect
an entry with IP number and database name. I don't see that information
in ODBC.INI in registry.

Comment: I was just wondering - do I have to install Oracle ODBC drivers on the client machine to enable ODBC connectivity?

Comment: I would expect you would have to install the drivers on the client.

Comment: I would too. The thing is that people at my company are using an ERP program created in PB. It uses local server as data source. I checked on one of the PCs: there is no Oracle client or drivers installed, no ORA Home directory, no Oracle related registry entries, no Oracle ODBC sources configured. Yet the program is running and retrieving data from server. I can't directly ask how is it organized but I'll try to figure it out. I don't know if it has anything to do but it seems they use something called Apache to distribute updates to users.

Answer (score 0):

Personnally, I use DSN. So, the only thing the PowerBuilder knows is the DSN name.  On that base, I establish the connection.
On the target PC, I configure ODBC with this very same DSN name and the necessary drivers.  This way, you have some flexibility in the deployment.  For instance, I can develop using DSN 'db', referring on my developper's machine to database 'dev' or the server 'server_dev' and deploy on a target machine where 'db' refers to 'prod' database on server 'productionServ'.
Compatibility issues aside, it can even be that the first one is MySQL and the other onee Oracle.
It is anyway crucial to install the drivers allowing you to access the desired database on the target machine and, if you use DSN, to configure it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you got confused with odbc.ini & registry, lets start from there.

Assuming the required ODBC connection is configured in your computer (as you said),

- Open registry editor (Win+R, regedit) in your computer.
- Go to path "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI". NOte: "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" can be used for multi-user computers.
- Right click on your "ODBC Connection"  and export. Save the file(*.reg). (opening this file in notepad will give you some ideas on how it is configured.)
- Also do the same for "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\ODBC Data Sources\". Merge both files into one (open the *.reg files in notepad and merge the text).

Now you have the following options to setup the ODBC in your target machine(s):

1. This file(*.reg) can be executed on the target machine (beware, the drivers path might be different in the target machines.).
2. If you have an installer, try to include code to write the registry values from the installer.
3. Use PB function RegistrySet() to create your own ODBC connection if it does NOT exists.

Brief of what we are trying: Export registry entries (as a *.reg file) from the development machine and create similar registry entries on target machines using any of the 3 methods listed above.